# Unity mesh - delete quads

Tags: unity, mesh

I'm trying to delete quads in unity. The code here creates a procedural grid. Setting the gridSizeX to 5 and gridSizeY to 3, creates a 6 by 4 grid. I want to delete the first row of quads when I click the left mouse button (later will implement a trigger to delete). I have created a DeleteTriangle() method but it doesn't work properly. I would like to delete all the quads in the first row when I first click the left mouse button. When I click again, it should remove the next row and so on. Here is the code I have:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
 {
   Mesh mesh;
   Vector3[] vertices;
   int[] triangles;


   public float cellSize = 1;

   public int gridSizeX, gridSizeY;

   void Awake()
   {
     mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
   }

   void Start()
   {
    MakeGrid();
    UpdateMesh();
   }

   void Update()
   {        
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
        DeleteTriangle(0);          
      }
   }

  void MakeGrid()
  {
    //set array sizes
    vertices = new Vector3[gridSizeX * gridSizeY * 4];
    triangles = new int[gridSizeX * gridSizeY * 6];

    //set tracker integers
    int v = 0;
    int t = 0;      

    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
        {
            Vector3 cellOffset = new Vector3(x * cellSize, 0, y * cellSize);

            //populate the vertices and triangles arrays
            vertices[v] = new Vector3(-cellSize, 0, -cellSize) + cellOffset ;
            vertices[v + 1] = new Vector3(-cellSize, 0, cellSize) + cellOffset  ;
            vertices[v + 2] = new Vector3(cellSize, 0, -cellSize) + cellOffset  ;
            vertices[v + 3] = new Vector3(cellSize, 0, cellSize) + cellOffset  ;

            triangles[t] = v;
            triangles[t + 1] = triangles[t + 4] = v + 1;
            triangles[t + 2] = triangles[t + 3] = v + 2;
            triangles[t + 5] = v + 3;

            v += 4;
            t += 6;
         }
      }
    }   

   void UpdateMesh()
   {
    mesh.Clear();

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
   }

   private void DeleteTriangle(int id)
    {
      Mesh currentMesh = mesh;

      var triangles = currentMesh.triangles.ToList();

      triangles.RemoveAt(id );
      triangles.RemoveAt(id );
      triangles.RemoveAt(id );

      currentMesh.Clear();
      currentMesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
      currentMesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();

      currentMesh.RecalculateNormals();
   }
 }
```

Comment: "I have created a DeleteTriangle() method but it doesn't work properly" — how does the behaviour of this method differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: well...right now this mehtod just deletes one quad at a time and deletes it column wise.... I would like the function to delete an entire row when I clcik the mouse button down...

Comment: So you tried increasing the number of entries you delete from your triangles array, naturally? How did that go?

Comment: I added two more line to the Update function: DeleteTriangle(3); DeleteTriangle(6);. After adding these the first quad got deleted but from the remaining ones, only one of the triangles was deleted. And it still deletes column wise and not row wise...